# Bigquery: Transform data in multiple columns into row-format

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Suppose the following table in BQ:

```
SELECT "Desktop" AS Device, 24 AS col1, 9 AS col2, 28 AS col3, 7 AS col4, 98 AS col5, 77 AS col6, 59 AS col7 UNION ALL
SELECT "Mobile" AS Device, 8 AS col1, 43 AS col2, 75 AS col3, 44 AS col4, 38 AS col5, 31 AS col6, 46 AS col7 UNION ALL
SELECT "Tablet" AS Device, 7 AS col1, 9 AS col2, 34 AS col3, 86 AS col4, 62 AS col5, 69 AS col6, 74 AS col7
```

Hereby, the table could be as large as around 100 columns.

I'd like to transform this query such that I have as resulting table:

```
SELECT "Desktop" AS Device, 24 AS Nr UNION ALL
SELECT "Desktop" AS Device, 9 AS Nr UNION ALL
SELECT "Desktop" AS Device, 28 AS Nr UNION ALL
SELECT "Desktop" AS Device, 7 AS Nr UNION ALL
SELECT "Desktop" AS Device, 98 AS Nr UNION ALL
SELECT "Desktop" AS Device, 77 AS Nr UNION ALL
SELECT "Desktop" AS Device, 59 AS Nr UNION ALL
SELECT "Mobile" AS Device, 8 AS Nr UNION ALL
SELECT "Mobile" AS Device, 43 AS Nr UNION ALL
SELECT "Mobile" AS Device, 75 AS Nr UNION ALL
Etc
```

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the number columns into an ARRAY and use UNNEST:

```
with raw as (
SELECT "Desktop" AS Device, 24 AS col1, 9 AS col2, 28 AS col3, 7 AS col4, 98 AS col5, 77 AS col6, 59 AS col7 UNION ALL
SELECT "Mobile" AS Device, 8 AS col1, 43 AS col2, 75 AS col3, 44 AS col4, 38 AS col5, 31 AS col6, 46 AS col7 UNION ALL
SELECT "Tablet" AS Device, 7 AS col1, 9 AS col2, 34 AS col3, 86 AS col4, 62 AS col5, 69 AS col6, 74 AS col7
)
select Device,  Nr
from raw
left join UNNEST ([col1, col2, col3,col4,col5,col6,col7]) Nr
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and the extra luxury here is that it does not depend on number and names of columns to be unpivoted

```
#standardSQL
WITH raw AS (
  SELECT "Desktop" AS Device, 24 AS col1, 9 AS col2, 28 AS col3, 7 AS col4, 98 AS col5, 77 AS col6, 59 AS col7 UNION ALL
  SELECT "Mobile" AS Device, 8 AS col1, 43 AS col2, 75 AS col3, 44 AS col4, 38 AS col5, 31 AS col6, 46 AS col7 UNION ALL
  SELECT "Tablet" AS Device, 7 AS col1, 9 AS col2, 34 AS col3, 86 AS col4, 62 AS col5, 69 AS col6, 74 AS col7
)
SELECT Device, Nr FROM raw t, 
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING((SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT(Device) FROM UNNEST([t]))), r'":([^,}]*)')) Nr
```

> Update for OP's comment : *I totally forgot to include in the requirements that the column names should also be added as a separate column*

```
#standardSQL
SELECT Device, SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET(0)] AS col, SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS Nr 
FROM raw t, 
UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING((SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT(Device) FROM UNNEST([t]))), r'["{}]', ''))) pair
```

if to apply to same sampled data result is like below now

```
Row Device  col     Nr   
1   Desktop col1    24   
2   Desktop col2    9    
3   Desktop col3    28   
4   Desktop col4    7    
5   Desktop col5    98   
6   Desktop col6    77   
7   Desktop col7    59   
8   Mobile  col1    8    
9   Mobile  col2    43   
10  Mobile  col3    75   
11  Mobile  col4    44   
12  Mobile  col5    38   
13  Mobile  col6    31   
14  Mobile  col7    46   
15  Tablet  col1    7    
16  Tablet  col2    9    
17  Tablet  col3    34   
18  Tablet  col4    86   
19  Tablet  col5    62   
20  Tablet  col6    69   
21  Tablet  col7    74
```

Comment: Thnx Mikhail, very handy in case of many columns. However, I totally forgot to include in the requirements that the column names should also be added as a separate column, so I know that for example the value 24 matches to 'col1' for the first row. Is this possible as well?

Comment: so why you accepted previous answer then? anyway post your new question or update this one with whatever you really need and I will answer or update my answer respectively. meantime consider voting up at least

Comment: anyway - see update in my answer and please don;t forget to vote up

Comment: Mikhail, to answer your question, I accepted the previous answer, since it met my initial requirements. My additional requirement came only later, with my first reply on your code. I'll take your feedback into account and next time I'll make a new post of it. Anyway, thanks for the updated code, this works perfectly.

Comment: sure, no problem, understood